# Remove overriden vf page from view button in order to get feed based enabled

Tags: overriding, case, feed, visualforce, salesforce-service-cloud

1. My standard view button is overriden by visualforce page.
2. I want to remove that page but it's contains visibility logic for custom button. That is when we create/save a record those buttons are visible based on the logic written in vf page.
3. I am unable to get feed view because of the overriden vf page on view button.
4. Is there any possible way to show buttons on the page and remove that vf page from view button?
5. my only attempt is to remove that vf page from view button.

Answer (score 0):

In Classic there are no extra buttons in new/edit mode, period. You can't achieve same functionality with a standard page layout, maybe using some console/sidebar hacks...

Have you tried doubling down on the visualforce override? You could create [`apex:tabPanel`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_tabPanel.htm) yourself, put `apex:detail` (like you probably already have) in 1 tab, [`support:caseFeed`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_support_caseFeed.htm) in another... It'll probably be ugly but close enough.

When do you plan to move to Lightning Experience? The other layout editor (App Builder) offers page sections you can conditionally show/hide and recently - even the [header actions/buttons can be shown/hidden based on some criteria](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lex_dynamic_actions_desktop_mobile.htm&type=5&release=230))